# Jetty Hot Code Replace Failed

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm developing a maven modular project with Spring and Vaadin that has the following structure:

```
|-- parent  (pom packaging)
 |-- model   (jar packaging)
     pom.xml
 |-- services (jar packaging)
     pom.xml
 |-- web-app  (war packaging)
     pom.xml
```

Now my trouble is that very often when I try to opdate my code during debug i get the following error

[image]

I'm deploying my web-app project using jetty embedded from eclipse using the following configuration

-XX:PermSize=256M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M  -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8080

[image]

What could be the problem? Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly nothing; not all code changes can be hot-swapped by the JDK. If you add or remove methods or change a method signature, it will already fail.

Comment: @Gimby Ok I knew this, but this also happen when I change the contents of a method

Comment: According to the error message - you changed the class hierarchy ("Hierarchy change not implemented"). This cannot be hot-swapped. Just restart jetty.

Comment: @Alexander I also get many time *Schema change not implements*